# GAS: is getLastRow() only valid for sheets, not arrays?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to save server calls and try to load the sheet into memory before other actions:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Condo1"); 
var allSheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  // load all sheet data into memory
var lastRow = allSheetData.getLastRow();
```

But the web console states:

```
Error   TypeError: allSheetData.getLastRow is not a function
at [unknown function](Code:9:28)
```

Is *getLastRow()* only applicable for sheets, not for other arrays of data?

I could not get an explicit answer in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getlastrow).

After help with the getLastRow() - thanks Marios! - I still am puzzled about the underlying objective, to **minimize server calls**. I have made a similar script where I get annoyed with the long execution time due to calling for every row, especially in longer tables. Now I wanted to make it better and manipulate the table locally. I am sure there are plenty similar issues on SO for google apps script, if I only could get a good search term. "async bulk request" did not give me good hits on SO.
Then I can start with selfstudy. Thank You!

Comment: You use array.length for 2d arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) `getLastRow` is a function applied to a [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object.

You are trying to apply `getLastRow()` to a 2D `JavaScript` array: `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2]]` and this is why you are getting a message that `getLastRow` can not be applied to a `JavaScript` array.

### Solution:

You have two options:

- Use the built in `JavaScript` array method [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) on `allSheetData` to get the number of "rows" this data array occupies:

  ```
  var lastRow = allSheetData.length;
  ```
- Apply `getLastRow` on the `sheet` object:

  ```
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  ```

### Please note:

Make sure to understand what [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) returns which is the last row in the sheet that has content.

In your case you are using [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) which implicity uses `getLastRow` to calculate the range. But if you want to manually define a range object, then `length` and `getLastRow` might give different results!